# Unable to display contact photo in phonegap through angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, contact-list

I am able to fetch and display the contact photo from simple html and javascript but when I use angularjs model to display the contact photo, I get an error. Following is my source code :

List where I am trying to display the contact :

```
<ul class="list">

   <li class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="contact in contactList">
            <img ng-src="{{contact.mphoto}}"/> <!--When I put this path directly ( ie "content://com.android.contacts/contacts/30/photo"), I am able to display the image, but when I fetch it from the controller, I am getting error: "unable to read contacts from asset folder" -->
           <h2>{{contact.name}}</h2>
           <p >{{contact.number}}</p>

   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my controller for setting ContactList :

```
ContactService.find("").then(function(contacts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
        {
            if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers !== null)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
                {
 var img = contacts[i].photos  != null ? contacts[i].photos[0].value : "img/default.png";

                    $scope.contactList.push({name: contacts[i].name.formatted, number: contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value, mphoto: img})
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this?  I'm having the same issue?

Comment: No luck yet, the same thing working in the IOS but not in android

Comment: @user1255162 please refer below answer might it will gonna solve your issue too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally after so much struggle I'll be able to find the issue,

Please paste the below lines in your App.js file and problem will get solved and the reason for not showing photo is that Angularjs adds unsafe: before each url if it is not trusted.

```
 config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|content):|data:image\//);
        }]);
```

Comment: awesome, well done for working this one out and thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: Wow, thanks for figuring this out Vivek, have been banging my head against a brick wall for the last hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: @reitoei Thanks :) i too have burned my 3 months to figure out this        :D

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could upvote twice. I originally went with the $sce.trustAs route which worked for iOS but not Android. This is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in Angular 2 with Ionic 2 but I didn't know this was the problem and I didn't know how to try the accepter answer in angular 2. For the sake of completeness, here is how you would fix it using Ionic 2:

Inject `sanitizer: DomSanitizer` in your controller/service.

then call: `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(photoURL)`

Here's an example:

```
export class HomePage {
  url;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      Contacts
        .pickContact()
        .then((contact) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(contact));
          if (contact.photos) {
            var photoURL = contact.photos[0].value;
            this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(photoURL);
          }
        });

    })
  }

}
```