# Phonegap, AngularJs and contacts plugin: how to render contact image

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I did a lot of search but was unable to find the correct answer.
I also checked other relative question in S.O. but they didn't help.

I use the Phonegap contacts plugin to fetch device contacts, one of the info is the contact picture, an object that has a 'value' property with a content like:

```
"content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1896/photo"
```

I haven't found a way to render this image, the classic

```
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" ng-src="{{item.photos[0].value}}" />
```

doesn't work.

I have contacts saved with an image taken from the device gallery, 
so I expect to display it.
The only thing I can see is a small white question mark with a blue background 
(I think it is the standard 'not found' image).

Permissions are set by plugin installation.

These are my currently installed plugins:

```
[ 'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.contacts',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer'
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
  'org.apache.cordova.network-inform
  'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen',
  'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]
```

Phonegap version 3.4.0
Cordova version 3.4.1
AngularJS version 1.2.16

I hope somebody could help, also with a solution that fits the AngularJS way.

Thank you

Comment: I'm about to deal with this same issue as I'm using phonegap and grabbing contacts as well, but i haven't gotten to the point of needing the image yet so I will star this and come back and giving and update when I figure it out.

Comment: I've spent a couple of days trying to make this works (with no success). And almost another couple of days to understand that there is the need to add the src="cordova_plugin.js" when using plugin. And days to correctly set up the environment with all the system variables.

Phonegap is a very interesting project but the documentation is often incomplete or old, it is difficult to go ahead this way. 

Anyway I still look for a solution, If I find one I'll post here.
Cheers

Comment: I hear ya man. I had similar issues and it took me a couple weeks just to get it to build without breaking and install the plugin correctly and return me my contacts... I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see this post?

Angularjs adds unsafe: before each url if it is not trusted.

[Unable to display contact photo in phonegap through angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682770/unable-to-display-contact-photo-in-phonegap-through-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment38369074_22682770)

Comment: I finally had the time to test this and it works! 
Thank you very much!