# Can't display contact photo in phonegap (angularjs)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to display my contacts photos.

I've get a list of photo of my contacts,
but when I try to show them in the view, I've got nothing ( except the standard broken image)

```
<img ng-src="value" height="28px" width="28px">
```

-> here, `value`is  `content://com.android.contacts[...]photo`

Following this [Unable to display contact photo in phonegap through angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682770/unable-to-display-contact-photo-in-phonegap-through-angularjs)

I've tried to add

```
config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
           $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|content):|data:image\//);
       }]);
```

At the end of my config file, but I've got a error (can't understant config)
so I've edit my file to be like that :

```
...


.config(function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when(.....)
     // rest of routing

  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|content):|data:image\//);

});

...
```

but Same here, nothing changed.

What did I've done wrong ?

Comment: What was the error you got?

Comment: the image just can't be displayed, I can't see if theres is an error

Comment: I was referring to the error you mentioned here: 'At the end of my config file, but I've got a error (can't understant config) so I've edit my file to be like that'. Either way looks like you arent evaluating the `value` attribite. Try `ng-src="{{ value }}"`